# Unable to limit width of Entry inside horizontal StackLayout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, .net-standard

Here's a simple test:

```
<StackLayout WidthRequest="300">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Entry x:Name="entry1" HorizontalOptions="Start"></Entry>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

When the `entry1`'s initial text is too long, it gets wider than the outside StackLayout, and we can't see its end.

What are the correct LayoutOptions for limiting the Entry's width (and the horizontal StackLayout) to the outer StackLayout's width?

Comment: Just set the `HorizontalOptions` of the inner Stack to `Fill`. The entry have a self scroll control and will allow the user scroll inside the entry to see the whole text dragging the cursor handler. It should works.

Comment: If you expect the text break line when it reachs the width control limit, the use another multiline text control

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `WidthRequest` on your `Entry` or it will expand based on its `Text` or `Placeholder` size, which StackLayouts like to auto-size depending on the size of their contents even with a `WidthRequest` set.

Another option would be to replace all your StackLayouts with a single `Grid` and your `Entry` shouldn't change the size of it.